# How do I have my vue variable be declared after the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using a `v-for` statement in my code:

```
<div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" :presence="user.presence" class="person">
     <span class="cardName h4">{{ user.name }}</span>
</div>
```

I created a variable `people` which held all created elements. When used in one function it worked, in another, it didn't.

On further inspection, it is empty in the second function. I would create one variable to be used by both, but the variable can't be created until the page renders (I tried lifecycle hooks, they didn't work either).

```
filterByName () { // this method worked
    const people = document.querySelectorAll(".person")
    
    console.log(people.length) // returned correct number
    console.log("Sorting by name")
            
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        let inner = people[i].getElementsByClassName("cardName")[0].innerHTML

        if (inner.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.sortName.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
            people[i].style.display = ""
        } else {
            people[i].style.display = "none"
        }
    }
},
filterByPresence() { // this didn't enter any for loops
    const people = document.querySelectorAll(".person")
    
    console.log(people.length) // this returned 0
    
    if (this.filterMode == 0) {
        console.log("Filtering by lack of presence")
        
        for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (!people[i].getAttribute("presence")) {
                people[i].style.display = ""
            } else {
                people[i].style.display = "none"
            }
        }
        
        this.filterMode = 1;

    } else if (this.filterMode == 1) {
        console.log("Filtering by presence")
                
        for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            if (people[i].getAttribute("presence")) {
                people[i].style.display = ""
            } else {
                people[i].style.display = "none"
            }
        }

        this.filterMode = 2;

    } else if (this.filterMode == 2) {
        console.log("Showing all")

        for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            people[i].style.display = ""
        }

        this.filterMode = 0
    }
}
```

So, my real question is: Why does one work but not the other, how do I get them both to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more information about how you call these two functions. In theory, they can work only in [mounted](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted) hook, please check this.

Btw, since you created these elements by `users`, why don't you just use `this.users` instead of `const people` and use `v-show` to control display style? If this.users is not in the component you are working on, you can consider about using props or Provide/Inject or pinia/vuex. Operating document directly may not be a good choice.

Comment: The interesting thing is that both methods are called from user events. In fact, I can call the first one and it will work, and then second one and it won't,  and then the first one and it will.